# Dependency Property Not showing in Property Pane

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

I attachted a Property to a WPF UserControl like this:

```
public partial class Datensatzliste : UserControl
{
    public int Modulnummer
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(ModulnummerProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ModulnummerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ModulnummerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Modulnummer", typeof(int), typeof(Datensatzliste), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    ....
}
```

The Control is hosted in a WinForms application. When I select the Control in Visual Studio, the property is not shown. Ho do I geht the Property to show up in the property pane?

[image]

Comment: It also doesn't show any of the normal properties, like Background or Visibility. Perhaps you must set their values from the code-behind of your Windows Form?

Comment: It is not the perfect solution I guess, but yes, the intellisense shows the property in the CodeBehind. So I just set it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the value of the property from the code-behind.